# Compass + Blueprint CSS = width of input tags is always 300px?

Tags: css, forms, blueprint-css, sass, compass-sass

While trying to find the reason for the problem, I disabled all my custom stylesheets. Now, I'm using only a single SCSS stylesheet:

```
@import "blueprint/reset";
@import "partials/base";
@import "blueprint";
@include blueprint;
```

This stylesheet leads to problem, however. In my entire application I'm using `<input>` Tags like the following:

```
<input class="span-17 title" type="text" size="30" name="customer[name]">
```

As you can see, I'm using Blueprint's `span-` classes for form elements. This has been working just fine without Compass.

However, Compass is generating additional style rules for form elements:

```
input.span-17, textarea.span-17, select.span-17 {
    width: 840px;
}
/* followed by: */
input.text, input.title, input[type="email"],
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    width: 300px;
}
```

With these two rules, all my input fields get a width of 300px (completely destroying my application layout). Why is Compass generating the second rule mentioned above (makes absolutely no sense to me)? And how do I prevent that behavior?

**Update:** Seems like I haven't been clear enough. I want to use Blueprint's `span-` classes on my form input fields. Setting all `<input>` widths to a constant value, isn't the solution I was hoping for. Instead, I'm looking for a way to make the `span-` classes work with Compass. Desired behavior is like Blueprint CSS without Compass - in any other case, I would have to change a lot of HTML templates - which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you remove the `size` attribute?

Comment: If you can put the `input.span-17, textarea.span-17, select.span-17 {
    width: 840px;
}
` after the other css, it will solve your problem.

Comment: Removing the `size` attribute had no effect.

Comment: @Niklas: Yes. But, all these styles are generated by `@include blueprint;` - which is part of Compass. I don't know about an easy way to control the behavior of this statement.

Comment: please check my updated answer and let us know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your CSS rules with a higher specificity.

Try something like this:

```
@import "blueprint/reset";
@import "partials/base";
@import "blueprint";
@include blueprint;

body input.text, body input.title, body input[type="email"],
body input[type="text"], body input[type="password"] {
    width: inherit;
}
```

or if the below part is in your own code:

```
input.span-17, textarea.span-17, select.span-17 {
    width: 840px;
}
```

you could enhance the specificity of your rules similarly:

```
body input.span-17, body textarea.span-17, body select.span-17 {
    width: 840px;
}
```

You can find more on CSS specificity (and its relation to Star Wars) in [Malarkey's article](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html).

[image: Malarkey's Specificity Wars]

Comment: @Wesley Murch: Rolled back your edit because the image actually explains the CSS specificity in a fun way. It is definitely not unnecessary and not "noise".

Comment: Yeah you're right. The image is not clear enough for me to read without zooming in a lot, but now that I read it, it is actually useful. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `@include blueprint;` brings in the whole show, including grid, forms, typography, etc.

If you don't want the input.span classes created automatically don't use that. Do just:

```
@include blueprint-grid;
```

Answer (score -2):

if it is possible you can override element width with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='text']", "input[type='password']").css("width","100px");
});
```

hope it helps.

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript or jQuery, and is not a good solution anyways. Why not a CSS solution to a CSS problem?